# Detect USB CDC device connection/disconnection using Java and RXTX

Tags: java, serial-port, usb, rxtx, cdc

I have an application that can run either with or without a USB CDC device attached to the machine. This device is programmed to respond to a question with a specific answer so I can detect which serial port is is connected to. The thing is, I need to know when to perform this check. I don't want to create a thread to run this check over and over again, so I need to know  how to listen to a "device connected" event. I have searched it before, but maybe I'm just not using the right key words, so any help would be very nice.

Obs: I'm using Java 1.7 and the RXTX library.

Comment: Have you tried jUsb api. long time ago I tried with that. you may check out that.

Comment: So you need a device connected event for a serial port?  Which OS are you using?

Comment: The device itself will run on Linux but the development is being made in Windows 7.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem and AFAIK there is no way to do this in a platform independent way.
On linux one might do it as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7115731/linux-usb-connect-disconnect-event).

Anyway, in case your device is a USB/Serial converter, you will only get an event when the converter is (un)plugged, not when a device is attached to the converter itself.